# Need help in retrieving the xmltype from a database select

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the below database table `CASH` with 5 columns:

```
REGISTER    DATE    CASE    BAG TYPE
1234    24-SEP-18   1123    112 A
1234    24-SEP-18   1124    113 S
1234    24-SEP-18   1123    116 S
1234    24-SEP-18   1124    117 A
7895    24-SEP-18   2568    119 A
7895    24-SEP-18   2568    118 S
```

Where the register number are the cash registers which can have multiple CASE linked to it and each CASE can have more than one BAG and Type attached to it.

What I want to achieve is as below:

```xml
<ROOT>
    <REGISTERS>
        <REGISTER>1234</REGISTER>
        <DATE>24-SEP-2018</DATE>
        <DETAILS>
            <BAG>1123</BAG>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>112</BAG>
                <TYPE>A</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>116</BAG>
                <TYPE>S</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
        </DETAILS>
        <DETAILS>
            <BAG>1124</BAG>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>113</BAG>
                <TYPE>S</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>117</BAG>
                <TYPE>A</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
        </DETAILS>
    </REGISTERS>
    <REGISTERS>
        <REGISTER>7895</REGISTER>
        <DATE>24-SEP-2018</DATE>
        <DETAILS>
            <BAG>2568</BAG>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>119</BAG>
                <TYPE>A</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
            <DETAIl>
                <BAG>118</BAG>
                <TYPE>S</TYPE>
            </DETAIl>
        </DETAILS>
    </REGISTERS>
</ROOT>
```

Could you please give some pointers how can I achieve this in an Oracle database select query? I don't want to create a stored procedure and want to achieve this in a select query.

Comment: FYI, the "code snippet" feature in the editor is meant for HTML+Javascript questions. For generic code blocks, use the `{ }` editor button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **please don't use Oracle reserved words ("date", "case", "type") as column names!** Double-quoting every column name gets tiresome.

So, this is a pretty complicated scenario. You're trying to do 3 levels of aggregation on the same table.

In addition, Oracle's XML Functions give you limited ability to construct XML on-the-fly in queries. The only way I know of to mix column (xmlelement) and row (xmlagg) data at the same level of the XML hierarchy is to concatenate them using the `xmlelement` constructor.

Also, I assumed that your "/ROOT/REGISTERS/DETAILS/BAG" tag was a typo and you meant it to be "CASE".

But I think this is what you're asking for.

```
create table cash (register number, "DATE" date, "CASE" number, bag number, "TYPE" varchar2(1));
insert into cash values (1234, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1123, 112, 'A');
insert into cash values (1234, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1124, 113, 'S');
insert into cash values (1234, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1123, 116, 'S');
insert into cash values (1234, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1124, 117, 'A');
insert into cash values (7895, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 2568, 119, 'A');
insert into cash values (7895, to_date('09/24/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 2568, 118, 'S');

select xmlelement("ROOT",
        xmlagg(xmlelement("REGISTERS",
                xmlelement("REGISTER", t1.register), 
                xmlelement("DATE", t1."DATE"),
                (select xmlagg(xmlelement("DETAILS",
                                 xmlelement("CASE", t2."CASE"),
                                 (select xmlagg(xmlelement("DETAIL",
                                                xmlforest(t3.bag, t3."TYPE"))
                                                )
                                    from (select bag, "TYPE" from cash 
                                          where cash."REGISTER" = t2."REGISTER" and cash."DATE" = t2."DATE"
                                            and cash."CASE" = t2."CASE") t3)
                               ))
                       from (select distinct register, "DATE", "CASE" from cash
                             where cash."REGISTER" = t1."REGISTER" and cash."DATE" = t1."DATE") t2
                       )
                )  
        )
    ) as xml_data
from (select distinct register, "DATE" from cash) t1
;
```

Output:

```
<ROOT>
   <REGISTERS>
      <REGISTER>1234</REGISTER>
      <DATE>2018-09-24</DATE>
      <DETAILS>
         <CASE>1123</CASE>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>112</BAG>
            <TYPE>A</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>116</BAG>
            <TYPE>S</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
      </DETAILS>
      <DETAILS>
         <CASE>1124</CASE>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>113</BAG>
            <TYPE>S</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>117</BAG>
            <TYPE>A</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
      </DETAILS>
   </REGISTERS>
   <REGISTERS>
      <REGISTER>7895</REGISTER>
      <DATE>2018-09-24</DATE>
      <DETAILS>
         <CASE>2568</CASE>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>119</BAG>
            <TYPE>A</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
         <DETAIL>
            <BAG>118</BAG>
            <TYPE>S</TYPE>
         </DETAIL>
      </DETAILS>
   </REGISTERS>
</ROOT>
```